# Creating a static C library for Linux that is portable across different GCC version

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, portability, abi

I'd like to distribute a static C library (.a) as a binary.

Given a certain CPU architecture and platform (e.g. armv6 / Raspi):

- Is it possible to create a single binary that works across all different GCC versions, i.e. is there an ABI across different GCC versions?
- Is it possible to use the same binary also from Clang?

If not, what GCC versions do I need to create different binaries for? Is it possible to use a very old GCC to build the binary and expect newer GCC versions to properly link it?

If multiple binaries are necessary: Is there any popular software that is distributed as a static library (.a file) that could be checked as a reference on best practices how to do this?

Would a shared object (.so) work better than a static library (.a)? Is there any ABI defined by Linux that allows programs that are compiled using different GCC versions to import a .so or .a library?

This question is not about C++. The library in question uses only C99 and is purely portable, i.e. not even dependencies on the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

For mature targets, GCC versions do not affect the ABI.  You can upgrade and keep using your old binaries.  This is also true for switching to Clang.

However, if your library depends on other bits (even just glibc), then at the time you build your library, you freeze the declarations and definitions in the header files, and future evolution of these dependencies can very well make what you have today incompatible with what users may have installed months or years down the road.

The GNU toolchain has much better support for ABI management of dynamically linked shared objects: Something that is properly linked against glibc or libgcc will continue to work for a long time.  With static libraries, this crucial linking step has not happened, and the ABI dependency is not properly encoded in the resulting static library.

Comment: In my case, no dependencies on the standard library exist. It is purely portable code. Also: Would you mind linking to some official documents that support ABI stability of GCC .o / .a files? Also, are Clang binaries also consumable by GCC, or only the other way around? And how to find out what is a "mature target"?

Comment: Also, what about flags like short-enums? Even with the shared object, how can a library ever be portable without requiring all of its clients to use the exact same flags?

Comment: @Etan: short-enums is an ABI-breaking option you simply *don't use*. If someone uses it, it's their fault they broke stuff.